# Issue with NewtonSoft.JSON version 9.0.1

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net

We have installed Newtonsoft.JSON (version 9.0.1) in our ASP.Net MVC project.

However in our web.Config file we have the `4.5.1` version loaded. This gives us an error as we need the `7.0.0` version or higher.

We tried manually changing it but that gives us another error. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: what's the other error?

Comment: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Maybe that should be your question then, it sounds to me like the referenced version somewhere else isn't the same as the one included, try making sure it's setup right, also check out some of the 'related' questions to the right of the question, they look like they may be quite helpful to you.

Comment: Try to update everything to use the same version, preferably latest. If some package you depend on needs a lower version, then perhaps upgrade that package or implement binding redirects.

Comment: **IF** this is (part of) a multi-project _solution_, and/or has dependences on other assemblies, that in turn have a dependency on NewtonSoft, then look into those as well. Hth...

Comment: For anyone visiting here, this version of newtonsoft 9.0.1 has a vulnerability https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-5crp-9r3c-p9vr and should no longer be used. Update to 13.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, I have used lower version but after updating to Version 9.0.0 I have got your mentioned exception.

but solved the problem by adding this in `Web.config`:

```
<runtime>
<shadowCopyVerifyByTimestamp enabled="true" />
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

try this and let me know your feedback.